# How to get indices of a 2D array from index of the masked array

Tags: numpy, indexing, mask

I need the original indices of a 2D array in a loop over the index of a masked array. I try:

```
for i in range(Arr[mask].size):
    tmp = numpy.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=bool)
    tmp[mask][i] = True
    j,k = numpy.where(tmp)
    ...
```

Unfortunately, last line returns

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

What is a good way to find j and k?

Comment: With boolean indexing `tmp[mask][i] = ` does not modify `tmp`.  `tmp[mask]` is a copy.  The `where` is accurate - there aren't any `True` values in `tmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a 2D array, you can simply iterate over the mask instead of iterating over the masked array:

```
for j, k in zip(*np.where(mask)):
    value = Arr[j,k]
    # ...
```

In case you additionally want to get the number of the current (masked) value:

```
for i, (j, k) in enumerate(zip(*np.where(mask))):
    value = Arr[j,k]
    # ...
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! Additionally, I use "for i, (j, k) in enumerate(zip(*np.where(mask)))" to get also index "i"

Comment: `np.transpose(np.where(...)` produces an array of the index pairs.  `np.argwhere` does the same thing.  `zip(*...)` is a list transpose.